# VS15 Remote Deploy for ARM not working

Tags: visual-studio-2015, arm, remote-debugging, windowsiot

I'm trying to deploy Win UWP app to RPi2 with IoT, I did this month ago successfully but since then I get few upgrades from Insider Program on Windows 10 and while I building and deploying project for Remote ARM now I'm getting following error:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: UWP1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
2>Creating a new clean layout...
2>Copying files: Total 17 mb to layout...
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
2>Registering the application to run from layout...
2>Deployment complete (2250ms). Full package name: "ffd6070a-f709-47e2-87c9-    c5bb4130e626_1.0.0.0_x86__bejdz9d3zy0yj"
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Couln't find solution for this problem on google :( Perhaps wrong keywords

Current build OS: 11102.1000 x64
VS15 Enterprise: 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Target IoT: 10586

Remote deploy error:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: UWP1, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>Updating the layout...
2>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout...
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
2>Framework: Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0/ARM, app package version 1.0.23430.0 is not currently installed.
2>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/ARM, app package version 14.0.22929.0 is not currently installed.
2>Installing missing frameworks...
2>Error : DEP0800 : The required framework "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime\1.0\.\AppX\ARM\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx" failed to install. 
2>error 0x800700C1: Opening the package from location     Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx failed.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is there any way how to install manually that missing framework?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out it was caused by wrong flashing using Windows IoT Dashboard which is somehow corrupted. Flash SD card using WindowsIoTImageHelper and it will work even REMOTE DEBUGGING!